# How can I make xcolor work from standalone documents?

Tags: color, standalone

I'm trying to use basic colors of the package `xcolor` from `standalone` documents, but the following error is returned:

```
main/filename.tex|29␣error|␣Package␣xcolor␣Error:␣Undefined␣color␣`MAGENTA'.
```

The main document has this:

```
\documentclass[10pt, b6paper, twoside, openright]{memoir}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.25cm}{.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout{}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[headings]{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents{}
    \dominitoc{}
    \input{mwedoc}
\end{document}
```

My standalone document (mwedoc) has the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[headings]{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter Title}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}[c]{ m{(\textwidth-0.5in)/2} m{(\textwidth-0.5in)/2} }
                \Large{\textcolor{magenta}First} &
                \Large{\textcolor{magenta}Second} \\
                \textcolor{red}{1. Mondays} &
                \textcolor{red}{1. Mondays} \\
                \textcolor{red}{2. Saturdays} &
                \textcolor{red}{2. Thursdays} \\ &
                \textcolor{red}{3. Sundays:}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \minitoc{}
    \newpage{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `\textcolor{red}{text that follows}` is the same as `{\color{red}text that follows}` and `\textcolor{magenta}Subtitle` is the same as `{\color{magenta}S}ubtitle`.  I don't know the answer to your main question.

Comment: Unrelated `\Large` does not take any arguments, but `\textcolor` takes two so `\textcolor{magenta} Subtitle` would make the `S` magenta. You should load `xcolor` in both documents, we cannot run the MWE you present here as `xcolor` is  not loaded, and I would assume that `\chapter` and `\minitoc` or the `fancy` pagestyle is available in that MWE.

Comment: I should probably start over with this question. None of the code you provided makes any sense of have any chance to be able to compile.

Comment: @Teepeemm Mostly, but not entirely. `\textcolor` issues an explicit `\leavevmode` first. There are situations where using `\color` alone leads to puzzling output.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, guys.  I finally made it to work by working on a better MWE.  I will edit the question to make it clearer.  Thanks again, all!

Comment: Compiles OK for me. - I should say, after removing `[headings]` option from `fancyhdr`.

Comment: Do you intend the `input` tex file to compile a document, rather than a standalone image? Because `standalone` class is based on `article` class, so will not have chapters; `minitoc` is incompatible with `standalone` class; etc.

Comment: This compiles OK standalone: `\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
            \begin{tabular}[l]{ ll }                
 \Large\textcolor{magenta}First &
                \Large\textcolor{magenta}Second \\
                \textcolor{red}{1. Mondays} &
                \textcolor{red}{1. Mondays} \\
                \textcolor{red}{2. Saturdays} &
                \textcolor{red}{2. Thursdays} \\ &
                \textcolor{red}{3. Sundays:}
            \end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Cicada - That would be more readable as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`standalone` package's basic default behaviour is that, for sub-files, it "ignores anything till the next `\begin{document}` and then takes the
document environment as a simple group" (`texdoc standalone`, s6.1 (p22)) - that is, in default mode, it skips over the sub-file's preamble, including the `\documentclass{}` command.

To demonstrate, take two input files: they both have the same content (a `tabular`), but one file is `standalone` *class* and colours the page background via a preamble command; and the other file is `article` class and colours the table itself with a `\colorbox{}{}` command.

The first sub-file is called `input1.tex` and when compiled on its own produces this:

[image: input1]

MWE

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{blue!12}
\begin{document}
            \fbox{\begin{tabular}[l]{ ll }                
    \Large\textcolor{magenta}First1 &
                \Large\textcolor{magenta}Second2 \\
                \textcolor{red}{1. Mondays} &
                \textcolor{red}{1. Mondays} \\
                \textcolor{red}{2. Saturdays} &
                \textcolor{red}{2. Thursdays} \\ &
                \textcolor{red}{3. Sundays:}
            \end{tabular}
            }
\end{document}
```

The second file, `input2.tex` produces this as the first item on a standard-size default page with a page number (page size and page numbering are defined by the document class):

[image: input2]

The full page:

[image: input2 as page]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!2}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
            \fbox{\colorbox{green}{\begin{tabular}[l]{ ll }                
    \Large\textcolor{magenta}First2 &
                \Large\textcolor{magenta}Second2 \\
                \textcolor{red}{1. Mondays} &
                \textcolor{red}{1. Mondays} \\
                \textcolor{red}{2. Saturdays} &
                \textcolor{red}{2. Thursdays} \\ &
                \textcolor{red}{3. Sundays:}
            \end{tabular}
            }}
\end{document}
```

Now, using `standalone` package in the main file and `input`ting both subfiles produces this:

[image: inputted]

In both cases, the sub-file preamble was skipped over, and just whatever was between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document` was imported into the main document.

The first sub-file's `\pagecolor{}` command, being in the preamble, has no effect on the `input`; the second sub-file's `\colorbox{}{}` command, being in the document body, carried over into the `input`.

In other words, `standalone` package's default is as if whatever is between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document` is just copy-pasted into the main document.

Sidenote: `standalone` package has options relating to how to deal with preamble code, e.g., consolidating multiple package options. Plus, in some cases, in particular where loading order of packages is important, sub-file preambles might need to be "carefully merged into the main preamble" and `standalone` package has an option to assist with this task (p23).

Now, `standalone` *class* (original intention: produce a single image in a cropped PDF canvas) does not have pages as such, so floats have nowhere to float to (so `figure` is useless), there are no headers to set because there are no margins (and therefore also there is no centering), chapters and other sectioning commands have no context and so error out (therefore no TOC). Etc. That reduces the actual input file to just the `tabular` (including corrected column-sizing code by @JohnKormylo from the other answer):

[image: input3]

Note: `magenta` is one of the basic 19 `xcolor` colours, so option `[dvipsnames]` is not needed. `Magenta` (with capital `M`) is a dvispsnames colour name (`texdoc xcolor` lists all the (defined) colour names).

Note 2: using `\documentclass[class=memoir]{standalone}` allows some usable settings from the underlying class to come through (font sizing and spacing settings). The default underlying class is `article`.

MWE

```
\documentclass[class=memoir]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
%    \chapter{Chapter Title}
%    \begin{table}[htbp]
%        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}[c]{ m{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.25in} m{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.25in} }
                \Large{\textcolor{magenta}First} &
                \Large{\textcolor{magenta}Second} \\
                \textcolor{red}{1. Mondays} &
                \textcolor{red}{1. Mondays} \\
                \textcolor{red}{2. Saturdays} &
                \textcolor{red}{2. Thursdays} \\ &
                \textcolor{red}{3. Sundays:}
            \end{tabular}
%        \end{center}
%    \end{table}
%    \thispagestyle{fancy}
%    \minitoc{}
%    \newpage{}
\end{document}
```

`input`ting that produces:

[image: include with 3]

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt, b6paper, twoside, openright]{memoir}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.25cm}{.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout{}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
%    \tableofcontents{}
%    \dominitoc{}
    \input{input1}
    \input{input2}
    \par\bigskip
    \input{input3}
\end{document}
```

---

For colours, use either the switch `{\color{magenta} text}` or the command `\textcolor{magenta}{text}` to colour "text" as magenta.

---

Although, having said all that, the usage of `standalone` is more nuanced: `standalone` class has options like `crop=false`, `multi=...` and even `float=...`, although, again, "In general it is recommended to keep floating environments inside the main document and only place the content of them into standalone files. This also makes it simple to include the same content in different floats of different main documents. If custom floats are defined using a package like `float` [they] are not supported yet. Dependent on the way they define floats they might still work." (p12)

---

In this case, it could probably be more efficient just to use `memoir` class instead of `standalone` class in the input files.

Comment: This was great! @Cicada, thanks for your time and for all the clarification!

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but a working memoir MWE.

There is no point in including things like `\chapter` or `\minitoc` in standalone class.  One can include standalone as a package (see section 6 of manual), but as far as I can tell, all it really does is define `\includestandalone`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[headings]{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter Title}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
            \fbox{\begin{tabular}[c]{ m{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.25in} m{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.25in} }
                \textcolor{magenta}{\Large First} &
                \textcolor{magenta}{\Large Second} \\
                \textcolor{red}{1. Mondays} &
                \textcolor{red}{1. Mondays} \\
                \textcolor{red}{2. Saturdays} &
                \textcolor{red}{2. Thursdays} \\ &
                \textcolor{red}{3. Sundays:}
            \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \minitoc{}
    \newpage{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The OP seems to be confusing two concepts:

1. importing code vs.
2. importing a graphic.

If you wish to import code, you use `\input` in the main document; however, the imported document behaves as if you inserted it (via typing) into the main document. Thus, the imported document cannot have a `\documentclass`, `\usepackage`s, or `\begin` and `\end{document}`. It inherits those characteristics from the main document.

On the other hand, if you wish to import a graphic, the standalone file should be fully self-sufficient with its own `\documentclass`, `\usepackage`s, and `\begin` and `\end{document}`s. In that case though, you first compile the standalone document creating a PDF.  Then, in the main document, you don't use `\input`, but `\includegraphics{mwedoc}` to display the PDF graphic of mwedoc.pdf.  Whether you place the `\includegraphics` inside a `figure` environment or not is a question of style, but the basic concept is the same.

Comment: Oh my..., now I understand  the difference.  Thank you! @Steven